# Nuxt static - API call

Tags: vue.js, amazon-s3, vuejs2, cors, nuxt.js

I'm having trouble dealing with API calls from NUXT static app.

Locally with `yarn dev` i can get it to work, but when i deploy it (tried with netlify and AWS S3 following this [tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/deploy-a-nuxt-app-to-s3-in-5-minutes-515a161eb74f/)), i get **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource** error when calling external API, and the dev tools shows the API call.

But as stated in the official NUXT docs *"All calls to APIs will be made and cached in a folder called static inside your generated content so that no calls to your API need to be made on client side navigation.([link](https://All%20calls%20to%20APIs%20will%20be%20made%20and%20cached%20in%20a%20folder%20called%20static%20inside%20your%20generated%20content%20so%20that%20no%20calls%20to%20your%20API%20need%20to%20be%20made%20on%20client%20side%20navigation.))"*, the API call shouldn't be visible in the dev tools, but i can see it (even in the dev env).

**I call the API inside a mixin, just like that:**

```
export const actions = {
  async fetchUpcomingGames({ commit }) {
    const response = await this.$axios.get('https://api.pandascore.co/matches/upcoming?sort=&page=number=1&size=100&token=MY_TOKEN')
    commit('setUpcomingGames', response.data)
  }
```

**Build settings on Netlify is like the [NUXT docs](https://nuxtjs.org/deployments/netlify/):**

```
Build command: yarn generate
Publish directory: dist
```

**In nuxt.config i have the settings created by yarn create nuxt-app, wchich is bassicaly:**

```
 target: 'static',
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
  ],
  axios: {
    baseURL: '/',
  }
```

It is a simple app with only one layout and one page, not a big deal. What am i missing ?

Comment: I'm not sure that Vuex is being able to do full static. [nuxtServerInit](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/store#the-nuxtserverinit-action) may be able to achieve that but I'll bet more on the usage of the `asyncData` and `fetch` lifecycle hooks.

Comment: Nice,  nuxtServerInit works like a charm. fetch only "hides" the calls if its been called in a route change ?

Comment: If you have a client-side navigation, you'll be using the client-side call yeah. It will still generate the template on server-side but on you won't have a server-side call once you move on the client (after the hydration).